# Laravel 5.2 - Authenticated User to Change Password - Password Matching Issue after Update

Tags: php, forms, laravel, authentication, passwords

So I'm having a rather odd issue. I've created a form that allows the user to change their password.

It does change their password. But it changes their password to something that Laravel can apparently not recognise.

So if I were to use "tinker" to manually update a password to something like "testing"; I'd be able to successfully change my password. However, once I'd changed the password to something (for e.g. 123456), the form wouldn't accept the password.

When I logout of the user and try and login with the new password; it wont let me login.

So clearly Laravel is not recognising the new password.

Code is here:

View:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Change Your Password</div>
            {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'security/change_password')) }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('current_password', 'Enter Current Password:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('current_password', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('password', 'Enter New Password:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('password', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm New Password:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('password_confirmation', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::submit('Change Password', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
                </div>                  
            {!! Form::close() !!}

    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function updatePassword(UserSecurityFormRequest $request)
{

    $user = Auth::user();
    $current_password = $request->input('current_password');
    $new_password = $request->input('password');
    if (Hash::check($current_password, $user->password)) {
        $user->fill([
                'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)
            ])->save();
    }
    else{
        return ('Please enter the correct password');
    }
}
```

I also attempted to set an attribute on password in the User..

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
    return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}
```

that didn't work. *(edit: I then removed the above attribute)* If anything it prevented the registration form (as part of Laravel's Default Auth system) from creating a password that the login form recognises.

I've checked to make sure that the form is submitting the correct details and it is. I did this by dumping all the data from the form inputs when the form is submitted successfully.

User Model:

```
<?php
```

namespace App;
use Carbon\Carbon;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//use App\Http\Controllers\traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

```
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

//If register dont work or passwords arent being recognised then remove the following:

/* public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
    return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}*/

//turns dates to carbon
protected $dates = ['created_at'];

     //Creates Many to Many Relationship between Users table (and model) and Roles Table (and model)
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class);
}


//Checks for a specific role
public function hasRole($role)
{
    if(is_string($role))
    {
        return $this->roles->contains('name', $role);
    }

    return !! $role->intersect($this->roles)->count();
}

//gives the user the role
public function assignRole($role)
{
    return $this->roles()->save(
        Roles::whereName($role)->firstOrFail()
    );
}

//Checks whether the user has a role with that permission
public function hasPermission($permission)
{
    return $this->hasRole($permission->roles);
}

public function owns($related)
{
    return $this->id === $related->user_id;
}
```

}

As you can see, I've commented out the attribute setter for passwords so that shouldn't affect it. Yet it still does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

It is not working. Massive thanks to everyone who responded and for @Steve Bauman for allowing me to indentify my mistake

Working function:
public function updatePassword(UserSecurityFormRequest $request)
    {

```
    $user = Auth::user();
    $hashed_password = Auth::user()->password;
    $current_password = $request->input('current_password');
    $new_password = $request->input('password');
    if (Hash::check($current_password, $hashed_password)) {
        $user->fill([
                                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)

            ])->save();
    }
    else{
        return ('Please enter the correct password');
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `User` model code. Is your `password` attribute in the `$fillable` attributes property? Otherwise, this code you've posted won't work.

Comment: User Model code posted. "passwords" is in indeed the $fillables property. Still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found your issue:

```
public function updatePassword(UserSecurityFormRequest $request)
{

    $user = Auth::user();

    $current_password = $request->input('current_password');

    $new_password = $request->input('password');

    if (Hash::check($current_password, $user->password)) {

        $user->fill([

                // This should be $request->password, not `$request->newPassword`

                'password' => Hash::make($request->newPassword)

            ])->save();

    } else {
        return ('Please enter the correct password');
    }
}
```

The requested variable `newPassword` would be empty, that's why your passwords don't work. The request field your looking for is `password`.

This is due to your form field using `password` as the input name.

Comment: Oh my.. this actually works! Thank you so much!! You're an absolute star! I got the "newPassword" from the documentation thinking it was a Laravel function..

Comment: Certainly not without your help. I'll update my post with what works in case anyone makes the same mistake as me.. though I doubt anyone would be that absent-minded!

Thank you again! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You make double password hasing, first in *Hash::make($request->newPassword)* second in setter *bcrypt($password)*

Remove one and everything should be okay.

Comment: Ah, I should have said but I removed the `public function setPasswordAttribute($password) 
{ 
    return $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password); 
}` after I'd realised it did not work. Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
bcrypt($request->newPassword);
```

Comment: I did: 
`if (Hash::check($current_password, $hashed_password)) {
         $user->fill([
                    'password' => bcrypt($request->newPassword)
                ])->save();
     }`
It did not work unfortunately.